# Yii2 captcha always incorrect

Tags: yii2, captcha

Whan I add 'on' => 'create' in my rule my captcha always incorrect
Off that work good why?
I try to let it to other controller support/captcha but still incorrect

MyView

```
 <?= Captcha::widget([
                        'id' => 'captcha',
                        'model' => $model,
                        'attribute' => 'verifyCode',
                        'options' => ['class' => 'form-control',
                            'data-v-rule' => '',
                            'captchaAction' => 'support/captcha',
                            'data-v-msg' => $i18n->t('please.input.verify.code'),
                            'placeholder' => $i18n->t('please.input.verify.code', '', false)]
                    ]); ?>
```

Myrule

```
...

        [['verifyCode'], 'captcha', 'message' => $i18n->t('error.verifyCode'),'captchaAction' => 'support/captcha' , 'on' => 'create'],
...
```

I get seesion

```
$_SESSION = [
    '__flash' => [],
    '__captcha/site/captcha' => 'nnbioo',
    '__captcha/site/captchacount' => 1,
    '__captcha/support/captcha' => 'cacijq',
    '__captcha/support/captchacount' => 1,
];
```

Mycontroller

```
public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => CaptchaAction::className(),
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: I had get verifyCode in post

Comment: But loss in model it say have no attribute why~~????

Comment: I had public $verifyCode in my model

Comment: solve by this way             $customerServiceModel->verifyCode = $post['CustomerServiceModel']['verifyCode'];

Comment: I don't know why model load  verifyCode  null

Comment: $customerServiceModel->load($post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$customerServiceModel->load($post)` is not working, because attribute `verifyCode` is not `safe` in this case. Your rule is specified with `'on' => 'create'` - so it means, it's save on scenario `create`. You didn't assigned this scenario to the model so there's 2 solutions:

1. Remove `'on' => 'create'` from rule
2. Assign `create` scenario to model by `$customerServiceModel->scenario = 'create';` before using `load()`.